# Force iOS simulator to use WiFi network

Tags: macos, wifi, xcode, network, xcode-simulator

I have two networks, a WiFi and a cable LAN.

I want use them together, but I want to force the iOS Simulator to use **only WiFi**, because, the LAN is under proxy, protected, with a lot of limitations.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe you can simply route one specific app through another network interface, but if you can define specific target hosts or subnets you could set up a different routing for those and route the rest to the first adapter in the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The iOS Simulator does not get its own internet connection, it uses the computer's. Therefore, if you want it to use the Wi-Fi network instead of the LAN, just make sure you're connected through Wi-Fi.

In **System Preferences / Network** you can rearrange the order in which the computer gains Internet connection. Just place Wi-Fi on top of the list. On **Lion** it's done by clicking the *gear* thingy, and select *Set Service Order* from the pop-up list.

[image]